# OpenMP no threading in subroutine

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm writing a matrix multiplication subroutine in Fortran. I'm using the Intel Fortran compiler. I've written a simple static scheduled parallel do-loop. Unfortunately, it's running on only one thread. Here's the code:

```
      SUBROUTINE MATMULT(A,B,C,L,M,N)
      REAL*8 A,B,C
      INTEGER NCORES, CHUNK, TID
      DIMENSION A(L,N),B(L,M),C(M,N)
      PARAMETER (NCORES=8)
      CHUNK=(L/(NCORES+1))+1
      TID=0
!$OMP PARALLELDO SHARED(A,B,C,L,M,N,CHUNK) PRIVATE(I,J,K,TID)
!$OMP+DEFAULT(NONE) SCHEDULE(STATIC,CHUNK)
      DO I=1,L
         TID = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
         PRINT *, "THREAD ", TID, " ON I=", I
         DO K=1,N
            DO J=1,M
               A(I,K) = A(I,K) + B(I,J)*C(J,K)
            END DO
         END DO
      END DO
!$OMP END PARALLELDO
      RETURN
      END
```

Note:

- There are no parallel directives in the main program that calls the routine
- The arrays A,B,C are initialized serially in the main program. A is initialized to zeros
- I am enforcing the Fortran fixed source form during compilation

I have confirmed the following:

- Another example program works fine with 8 threads (so no hardware issue)
- I have used the -openmp compiler argument
- OMP_GET_NUM_PROCS() and OMP_GET_MAX_THREADS() both return 0
- TID is 0 for every iteration over I (which shouldn't be the case)

I am unable to diagnose my mistake. I'd appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: If you use ntel Fortran, why don't you use threaded BLAS routines from MKL? You will never achieve similar performance yourself with this naive loop approach. I would not be surprised if even the normal optimized BLAS would be faster, than your OpenMP subroutine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying stuff out. DGEMM ran a bit slower than the loop. I still need to look into the compiler optimization options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identifier OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM is not explicitly declared.  The default implicit typing rules mean it will be of type real.  That's not consistent with the declaration in the OpenMP spec for the function of that name.

Adding `USE OMP_LIB` would fix that issue.  Further, not using implicit typing (`IMPLICIT NONE`) would avoid this and a multitude of similar problems.

Comment: Hi, I have a big code in fortran which contains several modules each of them with many subroutines. I compiled that code with the -fopenmp flag and in one subroutine I placed the !$OMP PARALLEL directive. Then, I put in the subroutine "use omp_lib". The problem is when I do "write(6,*)  OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()". It always shows 1 (1 thread) even if I use export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4. Where should I write "use omp_lib"? in each subroutine? in the main program? Thanks.