# Fortran program compiled with fopenmp shows only one thread

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, fortran90, gfortran

I have a big code in Fortran, it has a commercial license so that I cannot 
post the code. It contains several modules each of them with several subroutines. I compiled that code with the `-fopenmp` flag (I used the flag
for all files in the program).

In one subroutine I placed the code

```
!$OMP PARALLEL
       nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
       write(6,*) 'threads', nthreads
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Initially, the program complains about the unrecognized OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS data type. I saw some post on this forum and there
it was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646504/openmp-no-threading-in-subroutine/12646964?noredirect=1#comment48203865_12646964) to use `use omp_lib` to load run-time libraries . After
adding this line to the subroutine, the program ran but it printed

> threads 1

as if only one thread were used even when I set

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=10
```

My questions are, should I use `use omp_lib` in each subroutine? or maybe
only on the "main" program?

As I said before, this subroutine (where I wrote the `omp` directives) is 
inside a module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `OMP_Get_num_threads()` declared in the scope of the subroutine where it is used. This might happen with a `use` statement within that subroutine, or, since you are using modules, in the header of the module. In the snippet pasted below, I did both.

Note, that the function call to `OMP_Get_num_threads()` needs to be embedded in a parallel section (as you did in the code snippet), otherwise the result is always `1`.

Since the modules have no access to the scope of the main program, `use`ing the module there is not sufficient (but the compiler will tell you that when you are linking the binary).

```
module testMod
  use omp_lib, only: OMP_Get_num_threads
  implicit none

contains

  subroutine printThreads()
    use omp_lib, only: OMP_Get_num_threads
    implicit none

    ! This will always print "1"
    print *,OMP_Get_num_threads()

    ! This will print the actual number of threads
    !$omp parallel
    print *,OMP_Get_num_threads()
    !$omp end parallel
  end subroutine

end module

program test
  use testMod, only: printThreads
  implicit none

  call printThreads()
end program
```

with the following results:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./a.out 
           1
           2
           2

OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out 
           1
           4
           4
           4
           4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I wrote "use omp_lib, only: OMP_Get_num_threads" in both module header and subroutine and the output is always "nthreads 1" even when I use different values for OMP_NUM_THREADS. Is there a way to force the creation of threads inside a subroutine? Thanks.

Comment: Does the snippet I provided give the correct results?

Comment: but the solution you suggested didn't work in the other code I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Sorry, but I can only guess without seeing further code :( Please construct a minimal example from your code that shows this behavior!